# Brainfuck ide for OSX

Tags: osx, ide, macos

I want to try Brainfuck, and I would like to know if there is there any good Brainfuck ide for OSX?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so I searched the AppStore, Google and GitHub and I found some:

## FREE

- [BF interpender](http://www.softwaresea.com/Mac/download-BF-Interpreter-0-7-10008379.htm) `WARNING: I had never tried or read a review about this product and I don't recognise the website so it can be a virus`
- [Compiler Repo](https://github.com/enfiskutensykkel/bf-compiler)

```
extensions
```

- [VSCode Extension: Brainfuck Syntax](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=attilabuti.brainfuck-syntax)
- [VSCode Extension: Brainfuck Syntax Highlighter](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=swimmy4days.brainfuck-syntax-highlighter)
- [Atom Extension: Language Brainfuck](https://atom.io/packages/language-brainfuck)

```
all extensions are tested
```

## PAID

- [BF IDE](https://apps.apple.com/us/app/bf-ide/id1097560040?mt=12) it is also available at [itch.io](https://lucasmw.itch.io/bf-ide) **|** cost: `$9.99`

## Online

- [Copy.sh](https://copy.sh/brainfuck/) ide
- [Brainfuck Interpreter](https://gkucmierz.github.io/brainfuck-interpreter/)
- [Brainfuck Visualiser](https://fatiherikli.github.io/brainfuck-visualizer/#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)
- [Repl.it](https://repl.it/languages/brainfuck)